# Python3: Selecting and Copying a Random File Several Times Within Directory Tree

Tags: python-3.x

I am interested in copying random files from a Directory Tree. I tried example below and it works terrific for 1 directory of files, however I want it to search through multiple sub-directories and do the same thing.

Example:
[Selecting and Copying a Random File Several Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588257/selecting-and-copying-a-random-file-several-times/10107654#10107654)

I was trying to work out how to use either os.walk or shutil.copytree but not sure what to do. Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import shutil
import random
import os.path

src_dir = 'C:\\'
target_dir = 'C:\\TEST'
src_files = (os.listdir(src_dir))
def valid_path(dir_path, filename):
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
    return os.path.isfile(full_path)  
files = [os.path.join(src_dir, f) for f in src_files if valid_path(src_dir, f)]
choices = random.sample(files, 5)
for files in choices:
    shutil.copy(files, target_dir)
print ('Finished!')
```

I have updated this however I notice that os.walk is only giving me the last directory in the tree which has 5 files instead of 15 total from the root directory. Not sure where I am going wrong here:

```
import os
import shutil
import random

source_dir = "C:\\test\\from"
target_dir = "C:\\test\\to"  

for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
    source_files = filenames
    print(source_files) # this gives me 15 files whih is correct

print(source_files) # this gives me only 5 files which is only the last directory

choices = random.sample(source_files, 5)
print(choices)


for files in choices:
    shutil.copy(files, target_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok great thanks for the information, I have a working program now to collect random mp3s from my computer and put them on my phone. For those who are interested the code is below:

```
import os
import shutil
import random

# source directory for files to copy from
source_dir = "E:\\_Temp\\Music"
# target directory for files to copy to
target_dir = "C:\\test\\to"  

 # empty list for collecting files
source_files = []  

# walk through directory tree and find files only
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            source_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

# select 300 files randomly               
choices = random.sample(source_files, 300)
print(choices)

# copy files to target directory
for files in choices:
    shutil.copy(files, target_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursive way to do that:
Here you can find the answer.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read/55193831#55193831
```

Comment: Thanks, I read through this and Im a little stuck, I feel I am close as I have the random count section working, and the copy part working however I cannot get os.walk to store all files as a variable - only the last folder. example is: ```import os
import shutil
import random

source_dir = "C:\\test\\from"
target_dir = "C:\\test\\to"  

for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
    source_files = filenames
    print(source_files)``` gives me the correct files, 15 total.

Comment: when I do ```import os
import shutil
import random

source_dir = "C:\\test\\from"
target_dir = "C:\\test\\to"  

for path, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
    source_files = filenames
print(source_files``` I only get 5 files (last line is now not intented

Comment: You can try :  `os.path.isdir(filename)` from answer, if it is directory then you can store it into a list.
Hopw ir might help